# A way to extract datetime.now format from line?

Tags: python

I have a log file that contains lines such as

```
### 192.168.70.10 on 2018-06-19 23:57:37.846200 ###

### 192.168.70.11 on 2018-06-19 23:50:33.073267 ###
```

It may also contain other data on different lines.

I am wanting to print all lines that begin with ### and extract their date/time so that I can compare them with another date/time.

How can I do this? Should I use Regex?

Here is an example of what I am doing...

```
try:
    with open('myfile.log', 'r') as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            if "###" in line:
                x = line

            print(x)
            # get date and time from x

    myfile.close
except OSError as e:
    print (e)
```

Comment: Consider using [`if line.startswith("###")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to check for `"###"` at the _beginning_ of the line, instead of anywhere in the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex and the parse the captured group with datetime.striptime

This will allow you to edit the regex to match 1 or more whitespaces, etc.

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

with open('myfile.log') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        # Adding the ### into the regex allows you to remove the conditional if ### in line
        regex = r'###\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.+(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{0,})\s###'
        r = re.match(regex, line)
        if r:  # If there is a matching group, return matching group 1
            dt = datetime.striptime(r.group(1), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

        print(dt)
```

Comment: I would prefer [naming the group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in the regex `r"…(?P<dt>...)…"` and then [referring to it by name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) rather than offset: `r.group("dt")`. I think that’s a bit easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Naming groups is certainly useful. But when there is only one group the offset is easy to remember. And naming the group for someone who doesn't understand regex just makes the regex harder to comprehend

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in this type of problems

```
try:
  with open('myfile.log', 'r') as myfile:
    reg = re.compile('^###.*on\s([\w\s.:-]*)')
    for line in myfile:
       m = reg.match(line)
       if m:
         datetime.striptime(m.group(1), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Comment: Please fix indent and your code. Also, to improve performance, consider [compiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) the regex before the loop, and then use the compiled object to [match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match) the string. Also, remember that [search()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) can return `None`, so that needs to be checked too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a line has *always* the fixed format, then this should work:

```
# Extract the date and time substring.
s = x[-30:-4]

# Parse the string into a datetime object.
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

See the [`strptime()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for details on the template string.

If the format of a line in your logfile varies, then a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) might work (see [Daniel’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940964/a-way-to-extract-datetime-now-format-from-line#50941151)), or consider properly [parsing](https://pypi.org/project/parse/) a string.

Comment: I am getting ValueError: time data '018-06-20 09:12:30.360350 ' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f'

Comment: Yes, your log date string misses the `2` at the beginning, and your template string contains `:%f` instead of `.%f`.